# Link options ignored

Tags: linker, visual-studio-2012

Why do the command line version of the linker in vs2012 claim?

```
  [lib] LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/OPT:REF'; ignored
  [lib] LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/OPT:ICF'; ignored
```

They don't seem to be deprecated?
Is there any new order that one must follow with the link options?

Comment: Works on my machine™.  Type "where link.exe" to make sure you are not picking up an old version of the linker.

Comment: It was the correct linker but the output was a static lib, so the /opt ref should not be used here (aka could not be used). When I look at the output from link of the exe all is as it should be.

Comment: @Jonke You should leave it as an answer.